# i have listview in that messages are showing i want to show more button if label has more thaen 5 lines and less button on it

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a listview with a list of messages but need to show up to 5 lines and after that more and less button show on that and more button show only for messages which are more than 5 lines. I tried to do it like this but it's not working. The button is added to each and every label.

```
   <Label x:Name="TruncatedLabel"        
   MaxLines="4" 
   LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" 
   Text="{Binding plainContent}"/>
  <Button x:Name="ReadButton" 
    Text="[read more]" 
    Command="{Binding ExpandContractCommand}"/>
```

from above it adds readmore button to all labelsin listview, can anyone help me on this .

Comment: What does "i want to show more button if label has more thaen 5 lines and less button on it" mean? Could you provide more details?

Comment: Bind max line property within command code.

Comment: @WendyZang  hi ,i have LIstview with list of messages ,now if message length is more than 5 lines then i want to show readmore button and after exapanding full message need to show read less button there and if message length is less than 5 lines then dont need to show any button on message.

Comment: @Adlorem  bind max line but its not working ,

Comment: @Mayuri I do the test, but we could not judge the lines of the text, each device has different styles. Do you have some `/n` in your code to judge the lines of text?

Comment: @WendyZang no there is no /n in text ,because data is coming from server

Comment: Does it mean that your data has no delimiter? How you pass your data into list? Give an example of your code that is responsible for that part.

Comment: @WendyZang there is /n in text ,

Comment: @Mayuri You could create a custom control. To get the length of the text and get the width of device to caculate the lines. But, if you have `/n` in text, you need judge it and add a line of this.